# How to get the tridion broker content through a webservice call?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I need to access the dynamic broker content through a web service call for html5 based mobile website. we are on SDL 2011 version build:6.1.0.55920.

1. Is broker content already available as a web service?
2. Is there any configuration setup that needs to be done ?

Can anyone provide the guidelines needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Content Delivery OData web service that can be used to retrieve dynamic content from the Broker. To install it check the docs at the following locations:

.Net installation:
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_3E3A2FB1B4E34C20934B5A841C2E0930 (login needed)
Java installation:
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_DC046ED58691440E92ED1A8672851427 (login needed)

This information is also provided in the Installation Guide PDF.

For information regarding implementing the service check the docs at http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_DFBA3FF3977045F892ABB4FCF8DA38B1

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I started with a console app to retrieve the component data.                                        CDS.ContentDeliveryService cds = new CDS.ContentDeliveryService(new Uri("http://XXXXX/odata.svc"));

          var comp = from cp in cds.Components
                       where cp.ItemId == 12202 && cp.PublicationId == 12
                       select cp;  
   foreach (var xx in comp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xx.Title);
            }

  
            Console.Read();

Comment: How to retrieve  the metadata of the component?? i am getting a namespcae error when tried using              ComponentPresentationAssembler CPA = new ComponentPresentationAssembler();                                 string sComponentXML = CPA.GetContent(result, genericCT);   is there any other approach to fetch the metadata from the broker DB?

Comment: When using OData you don't need to use ComponentPresentationAssembler - that's kind of the point of having the webservice ;) All the information is available through the responses provided by the service. There's some useful info at http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/using-odata-with-tridion-and-net.aspx

Comment: I have gone through the above tutorials but  i am getting limited data(component info) like Title, published date etc,I am not getting the actual component xml data. I am not sure whether i  missed any configuration settings on the content delivery end. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the Component XML is available. You can get Component Presentation content though, so if you need the XML then you need to have a CT that publishes it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to modify the cd_storage_confe.xml file for querying the broker database. This file is present in bin\config folder of website.

Enable this tag:

```
<SearchFilter Name="SearchFilter" Class="com.tridion.broker.components.meta.MsSqlSearchFilterHome" defaultStorageId="defaultdb"/>
```

After this, you can use the Broker query mechanism to fetch the content from broker database and display the data dynamically.

More help on [SdlLive website](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_0AB6D192D7AB4EC18892631F519EF1DD#url=http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com:80/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=broker%2520query%2520mechanism&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1349850677589&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_B5D7EADECD2E4C74AB3F044240C3FC46&query=&scope=&filename=DynamicContentRetrieval.xml&docid=concept_B5D7EADECD2E4C74AB3F044240C3FC46&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) (login required)